# Using deprecated TabBar and SherlockActionBar in Android v.4

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I am using the deprecated Tab Bar at the bottom of my App. [an example of my Tab Bar](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/).

Then I used the `ActionBarSherlock` at the top of my Application. It works pretty fine for Android v2.3.5 and version3.2,

but when I run it on Android v4, the `ActionBar` disappear, and items on `ActionBar` appear as option-menu and the sub-menus appear as context-menu.

I can not change the architecture and use fragment instead of deprecated Tab Bar.

Do you have any idea how can I make the `ActionBar` appear in Android v4 ?

Or do you think it is impossible since I can not use fragment in this case.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Styled);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_settings:
            System.out.println("Hello");
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

And style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Title on action bar -->
     <style name="TitleText" >
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12.5dip</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Aas far as I know you must use fragments with ActionBar. Fragments are supported in v4 support library. Changing from activities to fragments shouldn'g be hard. And can you post screenshots of what you see on v4 device?

Comment: You can see in the images how the context menu look like: http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/. They are my sub menus.

Comment: I know how they look like. I wanted so see the whole picture what's wrong in your case.

Comment: As I said my ActionBar in v 2,3 is disappeard and items are appeared as option and context - menus.

Comment: Did you use Theme.Sherlock as your app theme for v2.3? Did you extend SherlockActivity? Provide more details! And if you use ActionBarSherlokc - it would be bad not using it's wonderful tab feature.

Comment: You can see the code details at the end of the question. @DoctororDrive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in your application it's better to use `SherlockFragmentActivity` and `SherlockFragment` as it's content. At least in my opinion. Second on early versions of Android the actionbar items will be shown only when you set this value for them : `android:showAsAction="always"` .

For example :

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/sync"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Sync"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="always"   />
```

In devices which has hardware menu button, the rest of elements will be places as sub-menus even if the android which you are running the app is 3+.

Using deprecated TabBar is not a problem for you, but there is a good example on how to use tabs with `ActionBarSherlock` using `Fragments` which you can find here : [FragmentTabManager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java)